# Solve the equation $(x^2-9)+\sqrt{2-x}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $(x^2-9)+\sqrt{2-x}=0$

1. $(x+3)(x-3)+\sqrt{2-x}=0$

   Conditions: $x\neq\pm3 \wedge x\leq2$
2. $(x+3)(x-3)     = -\sqrt{2-x}$
3. $(x+3)^2(x-3)^2 = 2-x$
4. $x^4-18x^2+81   = 2-x$
5. $x^4-18x^2+x+79 = 0$

I'm positive this isn't going to the right direction.

Please help.

Comment: You mean $(x^2-9)+\sqrt{2-x}=0$?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Your "5." is right. But I don't see any sense in splitting $(x^2-9)$ to $(x+3)(x-3)$. Such unnecessary calculations can give rise to calculation errors that simlply can be avoided by avoiding such  calculations.

Comment: I'm trying it in a sign diagram now. Or is that not correct? How would you have done it? I don't see what I can do else with (x²−9)

Comment: $x$ can be $3$ or $-3$ !!

Comment: I already have done that in my calculation idm. Since miracle173 is seeing that as pointless. I'm asking what else I can do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will be $x\approx -2.6175$. (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-18x%5E2%2B81%3D2-x). You can find its closed form if you want.)

Here, notice that we have $-3\le x\le 2$ because of $9-x^2=\sqrt{2-x}\ge 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by 9-x²=Squareroot 2-x?

Comment: @hiisitmeyoulookingfor: Since we have $9-x^2=\sqrt{2-x}$, we have $9-x^2\ge 0$ because of $\sqrt{2-x}\ge 0$. So we have $9-x^2\ge 0\iff -3\le x\le 3$. Hence, with $x\le 2$, we have $-3\le x\le 2$.

Comment: That is to difficult for me. I don't understand how your square 2-x can be positive when you take it to the other side. I don't know what ⟺ is

Comment: @hiisitmeyoulookingfor: Well, OK. You know $\sqrt{x}$ is defined only when $x\ge 0$, right? So we have $2-x\ge 0$, namely $x\le 2$. On the other hand, $\sqrt{x}\ge 0$ holds for any $x\ge 0$. So, we have $9-x^2=\sqrt{2-x}\ge 0$, namely $9-x^2\ge 0$. Then, can you solove $9-x^2\ge 0$ for $x$?

Comment: How would you do the sign diagram then. I have to draw one. Please show me your way. +1

Comment: @hiisitmeyoulookingfor: At first, we have $x\le 2$. Also, we have $-3\le x\le 3$, which comes from $9-x^2\ge 0$. Hence, we have $x\le 2$ and $-3\le x\le 3$, so we have $-3\le x\le 2$. I don't think I can explain these things more kindly...

Comment: My answer was: x≤2  and −3≤x≤3 your answer is −3≤x≤2 .  because −3≤ is also in −2≤? Sorry Im not the brightest :D

Comment: @hiisitmeyoulookingfor: You are right with "$x\le 2\ \text{and}\ -3\le x\le 3$". Then, this can be simplified as $-3\le x\le 2$, which I wrote. Now, $x\le 2$ means $x$ has to be less than or equal to $2$. Also, $-3\le x\le 3$ means $x$ has to be larger than or equal to $-3$ and has to be less than or equal to $3$. Now, since $x$ already has to be less than or equal to $2$, we have $-3\le x\le 2$. I hope this helps!

Comment: I really appreciate it! Thanks for explaining with patience :)! I get it

Comment: @hiisitmeyoulookingfor: Oh, I'm glad to hear that. You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve (or approximate) such an equation (or to simply check how many solutions exist) is to graph each side of the equation: $$x^2 - 9 = -\sqrt{2-x}$$

- $y_1 = x^2-9$
- $y_2 = -\sqrt{2-x}$

Then look for when $y_1 = y_2$: if there are solutions to this equality, they will appear as points where $y_1$ and $y_2$ intersect.

See the top graph: The blue parabola is $y_1 = x^2 - 9$. The domain of $x$ shown in the purple graph is $x\leq 2$.

[image]

There is exactly one real solution: the point of intersection of the two graphs is $$(x, y) \approx (-2.61747, -2.14883)$$

So the one real solution is $x \approx -2.61747$.

Comment: Wow that is clear. Thanks for explaining what the answer means. But I can't use a graphical calculator on my exam and also don't know how I would draw one myself. +1

Answer (score 2):

Consider making a sign diagram. You will get your answer if you fill in (x+3)(x-3) and ...

Comment: I'm going to try that.

Comment: @hiisitmeyoulookingfor: I think this is an answer to the first version of your question (without the '+').

Comment: Thank you. I got my sign diagram now and with that my answer to x!

Comment: You're welcome.